# Java - Reading a Text File and Adding a Unique ID

Tags: java

I am trying to learn Java and am really struggling on part of a problem that I have.  I am being asked to write a method to read a text file where each line representing an instance of an object e.g. SalesPerson

The question is asking me to add an identifier id for every line that read in, the id is not present in the text file.  I have id declared in my Sales Person class with a constructor and getter and setter methods, and have my method to read the text file below in another class.  However it doesn't work and I am not sure where I am going wrong.  Could someone give me a pointer..?  I would be very grateful.,

```
public static Collection<SalesPerson> readSalesData() {
    String pathname = CXU.FileChooser.getFilename();
    File aFile = new File(pathname);
    Scanner bufferedScanner = null;
    Set<SalesPerson> salesSet = new HashSet<>();

    try {
        int id;
        String name;
        String productCode;
        int sales;
        int years;
        Scanner lineScanner;
        String currentLine;
        bufferedScanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(aFile)));

        while(bufferedScanner.hasNextLine()) {
            currentLine = bufferedScanner.nextLine();
            lineScanner = new Scanner(currentLine);
            lineScanner.useDelimiter(",");
            id = salesPerson.getId();
            name = lineScanner.next(); //return the next token as a string
            years = lineScanner.nextInt();
            productCode = lineScanner.next(); // return the next token as a string
            sales = lineScanner.nextInt(); // return the next token as a double
            salesSet.add(new SalesPerson(id, name, years, productCode, sales));   
        }
    }
    catch (Exception anException) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + anException);
    }
    finally { 
        try {
            bufferedScanner.close();
        }
        catch (Exception anException) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + anException);
        }
    }
    return salesSet;
}


\\Constructor from Class SalesPerson
public SalesPerson(int aId, String aname, int aYears, String aProductCode, int aSales) {
    super(); // optional
    this.id = ++nextId;
    this.name = aname;
    this.years = aYears;
    this.productCode = aProductCode;
    this.sales = aSales;
}
```

Comment: where did you declare `salesPerson` in line `id = salesPerson.getId();`

Comment: Also, can you be specific about what is not working? If it won't compile, what is the error. If it compiles but crashes, what is the error message? If it doesn't crash but produces the wrong output, what is the output? Providing these will help us to help you. Good luck!

Comment: Keep a counter inside the while loop. Initialize it to 0 and incremented by 1 for each line read from file. Use the counter as a unique id for your objects.    
   
`...new SalesPerson(++counter, name, years, productCode, sales));`

Comment: fram - sorry my version control leaves alot to be desired - so I can't replay the error message.

Comment: harsh - I didn't declare it :-(

Comment: Ella - I like your solution but unfortunately I can't use it as I have declare the count a specific way :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the following code I tried to make things little more simple:

```java
package com.project;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Temp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<SalesPerson> salesPersons = (Set<SalesPerson>) readSalesData();

        System.out.println(salesPersons.toString());
    }

    public static Collection<SalesPerson> readSalesData() {
        Set<SalesPerson> salesPersons = new HashSet<>();

        try {
            File file = new File("D:/file.txt");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.isEmpty())
                    break;

                String[] rowData = line.split(";");
                salesPersons.add(new SalesPerson(rowData[0].trim(), Integer.parseInt(rowData[1].trim()), rowData[2].trim(), Integer.parseInt(rowData[3].trim())));
            }

            fileReader.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }

        return salesPersons;
    }
}


package com.project;

public class SalesPerson {

    // Static to keep reserve value with each new instance
    private static int AUTO_ID = 1;

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int years;
    private String productCode;
    private int sales;

    public SalesPerson() {

    }

    public SalesPerson(String name, int years, String productCode, int sales) {
        this.id = AUTO_ID;
        this.name = name;
        this.years = years;
        this.productCode = productCode;
        this.sales = sales;

        AUTO_ID++;
    }

    // Getters & Setters...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ID: " + id + ", Name: " + name + ", Years: " + years + ", Product Code: " + productCode + ", Sales: " + sales + System.lineSeparator();
    }
}
```

And this my data file:

```
FullName1 ; 20; p-code-001; 10
FullName2 ; 30; p-code-002; 14
FullName3 ; 18; p-code-012; 1040
```

Comment: Hey Hussein - thank you so much!  Your method worked - however I have one slight issue.  My constructor for SalesPerson can only take a String argument representing name.  So I am not sure how to re-build this constructor to get the same outputs.

Comment: Hey @Barca1878, you are welcome please could you provide more info ?? I didn't get which output you referring to.

Comment: Hi Hussein pls ignore my last question.  This appears to work if I call the method using this command Collection<SalesPerson> bob smith = temp.readSalesData(); - however I need to call the method using temp bob smith = new temp(); temp.readSalesData .  Any ideas why this doesn't work like that?

Comment: This seems as invalid java declaration `temp bob smith = new temp();` would you mind to clarify ? you could DM if you want... and please could you mark my answer as approved !!

Comment: @Hussien Akar - can you DM me so I can respond and find out how to mark your answer as approved?  Still finding my feet with this website :-)

Comment: Sorry @Barca1878 I'm also new here ! thought my email is public anw this is my email hussein.akar992@gmail.com you could contact me and to mark the answer as accepted simple press the arrow-up on the left on my  answer like explained here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments